# How to use .map() and request to get base64 data from Url and return new array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Nodejs I have the function to make base64Data from my Url, I just don't understand how i've been unsuccessful at pulling data from the function. I am new at using Promises to get the product returned from a function. I think this might be my issue here. I am attempting to get base64 data from using `request` npm. I have an array of Url's sent from the front-end and need to map through each of them to get the base64 data. I then am trying to push the data into a new Array which will display the base64 data of each Url.

Here is something I have tried doing..

```
const getbase64Data = (files) => {
    files.map((image, index) => {
      request.get(image, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          data =
            "data:" +
            response.headers["content-type"] +
            ";base64," +
            Buffer.from(body).toString("base64");
          let array = [];
          array.push(data);
        }
      });
    });
    return array;
  };

console.log(getbase64Data(signatures));
```

When I console.log like above, it returns as an empty array. I'm assuming that it's the way that Javascript is being read.

**Edit:**

Request has an error of

```
Error: Invalid protocol: data:
    at Request.init (/Users/node_modules/request/request.js:458:31)
    at new Request (/Users/node_modules/request/request.js:127:8)
    at request (/Users/node_modules/request/index.js:53:10)
    at /Users/node_modules/request/index.js:61:12
    at Function.get (/Users/node_modules/request/index.js:100:12)
    at /Users/routes/api.js:327:15
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at getbase64Data (/Usersroutes/api.js:326:18)
    at /Users/routes/api.js:360:15
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Comment: the variable named array is defined inside the map function, but you are trying to return it from the outside function. Try `return files.map(....`. Array.prototype.map uses a callback to transform one array into another array. See [moz](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) You're letting errors fail silently. You might want to console log something inside the callback for request.get if you fail to get an  image.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the error, I have updated the details with the error